# Going back to my main activity, and refreshing the fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

So, my application have one activity `ProjectActivity` as a home, which contains 3 fragments `HomeFragment` `ListFragment` `TagFragment`(one for each tab). When I click on a button (on the `homeFragment`), it opens a new activity `CaptureActivity`.
That activity launches an ASyncTask, `ParseData`.

On the `ParseData` onPostExecute, I would like to go back to my `ProjectAcitity`, focused on a specified tab (the one that contain `ListFragment`), and update the `ListFragment` View.

I actually have no clue on how to do that. Do I simply need to call the `ProjectActivity` ? But then, if I press the Back button, wouldn't it go back through the whole chain (`Project Activity`, `CaptureActivity`, `ProjectActivity`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do a few things.

First just have ListFragment monitor w/e its listing and refresh it in its onStart/onResume which will be called when you return to your ProjectActivity.

Or more directly you could do startActivityForResult(captureActivity); then when u come back to your ProjectActivity get results in onActivityResults() then update your ListFragment from there.

Comment: Well, I did that and it works. I'm not sure I'm updating the ListFragment like I should (my ListFragment is a TableLayout, and I don't want to modify the TableRow already initialised), but it works, so thank you :)